# Git ignoring all minified suffixed files

Tags: git, gitignore

I currently have something like:

```
javascripts/
    plugin.js
    plugin.min.js

stylesheets/
    style.css
    style.min.css
```

How would I get all `.gitignore` to ignore all minified (`.min`) files? Would something like `**/*.min.*` work?

Comment: Only js and css has min file, right? Add *.min.js and *.min.css

Answer (score 39, accepted):

You have several solutions, depending of what you really need.

**Ignore all minified files in your project :**

```
*.min.*
```

**Ignore all minified files in a folder :**

```
assets/*.min.*
```

**Ignore only JS/CSS minified files in your project :**

```
*.min.js
*.min.css
```

Comment: Any idea why this doesn't work? I added `*.min.*` but `git status` still returns bunch of .min.js files...

Comment: Experiencing the same thing. Using `*.min.*` in a top level .gitignore, yet still all `foo.min.bar` files are being included.

Comment: if you have already checked them in, you have to delete them from the repository.

Comment: `*.min.js` will only ignore `.min.js` files in current directory. You need to use `**.min.js` to ignore all `.min.js` files in your entire project.

Comment: I don't think that's correct, IIRC ([and the documentation do seems to support this](https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore#_examples)) it will search for files in subdirectories by default, unless you're explicitly adding a leading slash.

Answer (score 5):

I believe you have to `git rm filename --cached` to remove the files from your git repo if you added it to .gitignore afterwards. (note: this will remove it from the repo, not from directory)

Answer (score 3):

just having this in the gitignore should work

```
*.min.*
```