# .gitignore two or more extensions file

Tags: git, gitignore

I have the next files in my local repository:

`app.component.js
core.component.js
core.service.local.js
core.service.power.ts`

My question is very simple, How can I do to ignore the files with the extension .component.js and .service.local.js and other, I mean any file to end with .Any_String.ext

Comment: Possible duplicate of [explain gitignore pattern matching](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33189437/explain-gitignore-pattern-matching)

Comment: My two cent about gitignore stuffs ... https://github.com/github/gitignore

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Git ignoring all minified suffixed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987084/git-ignoring-all-minified-suffixed-files)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a wild character '*'. Example `*.component.js`

Comment: This is valid for the shown examples, but the question is how to ignore when the last two "words" in the filename are not known. (i.e. ".Any_String.ext" as show at the end of the question)

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to add these to your `.gitignore` file.

use this command to stop tracking the specific file

```
git rm --cached .
```

or

In this case you can stop tracking the below file.

```
git rm --cached public/app/core.service.local.js
```

or

Add these in your `gitignore` file. I'm not sure you want to skip all files with *.component.js or just only these 4 files.

```
app.component.js
core.component.js
core.service.local.js
core.service.power.ts
```

Or use wildcard representation and make sure you ignore unwanted files only.