# *.min.* in gitignore is not ignoring .min.js files

Tags: git

```
## Ignore Visual Studio temporary files, build results, and
## files generated by popular Visual Studio add-ons.

# User-specific files
*.suo
*.user
*.userosscache
*.sln.docstates
*.orig
*.min.*
```

these are the first few lines of my git ignore files and I can't seem to figure out why git is not igoring any of my .min.js files. I've already checked other questions on here but can't seem to figure out why still. Also, the min.js files are being re-generated every time I compile. Am I doing something wrong here? Also using Git-Extensions if that helps at all.

Comment: Are the `min.js` files already part of the repository?

Comment: @hjpotter92 You're right, they are, ah I can't believe I forgot that. Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to stop tracking and ignore changes to a file in Git?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936249/how-to-stop-tracking-and-ignore-changes-to-a-file-in-git)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
*.min.*
```

is the correct syntax but that is not working if the files are added once to your repo. Then you have to remove them first from your repo to ignore that files.

```
git rm --cached filename
```

[Git ignoring all minified suffixed files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25987084/git-ignoring-all-minified-suffixed-files)